# Thickbox loading but Image does not show

Tags: jquery, lightbox, thickbox

I implemented Thickbox on my website but I have a problem.

Once the image is clicked the loader appears but then dissapears leaving just the overlay.

I checked from Firebug that the TB_window has the css visiblity:hidden.

Once I change it from there the thickbox comes up.

I already tried changing thickbox.js and setting its visiblity with Jquery

Any one got an idea what should I do ?

Comment: From the Thickbox homepage: While Thickbox had its day, it is not maintained any longer, so we recommend you use some alternatives. * colorbox * jQueryUI Dialog * fancybox * DOM window * shadowbox.js -The Management. 9.30.2009 (and Paul Irish)